# factory class duplicate insert check in magento2

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model, factory

I have created a model class as like below.

**Vendor\Module\Model/Bulider.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\QualificationException;
 class Builder extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
}

/**
 * @return void
 */
public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Builder');
 }

}
```

then **Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Builder.php**

```
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

 class Builder extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

protected $_builderFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\BuilderFactory $_builderFactory
)
{
    $this->_builderFactory = $_builderFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('builder_table', 'id');
}

public function builder($pid,$type,$id,$date) {
    $log = $this->_builderFactory->create();
    $log->setPId($pid);
    $log->setProductType($type);
    $log->setUnitId($id);
    $log->setCreatedAt($date);
    $log->save();
  }
}
```

I have injected this class in my controller and inserting data as like below.

```
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

 protected $_builderResourceModel;
 protected $_storeManager;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Builder $builderResourceModel
 ) {
    $this->_storeManager     = $storeManager;
    $this->_builderResourceModel = $builderResourceModel;
    parent::__construct($context);
 }

 public function execute()
 {
   $result = array();// this is the model data
   $modelId = $result['id'];
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   foreach($result['core_units'] as $unit){
      $type = "C";
      $this->_builderResourceModel->builder($modelId,$type,$unit,$date);
   }

    foreach($data['optional_units'] as $option){
       $type = "O";
      $this->_builderResourceModel->builder($modelId,$type,$option,$date);
    }

   }
}
```

the current data structure is like below

[image]

A sample result data is given here

> ```
>   Array
>    (
>      [id] => 2    
>      [core_units] => Array
>      (
>         [0] => 31
>         [1] => 63
>      )
>       [optional_units] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 31
>         [1] => 63
>         [2] => 82
>        )
>      )
> ```

so, while inserting data i need to check for the duplicate data insert.

Before inserting i need to check if same data exist or not in the table, if data exist with same i need to update otherwise i need to insert new row.

Can this be achieved any other way. Please someone look into it and update me your ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify **builder** method following way:

```
public function builder($pid,$type,$id,$date)
{
    $log = $this->_builderFactory->create();
    $log = $log->load($pid, 'p_id');
    if (!$log->getId()) {
        $log = $this->_builderFactory->create();
    }
    $log->setPId($pid);
    $log->setProductType($type);
    $log->setUnitId($id);
    $log->setCreatedAt($date);
    $log->save();
}
```

Comment: hi @Sohel,this code will update the existing record?

Comment: yes............

Comment: I need to insert new row only if not found the record with same values for all field, right now you are checking with only p_id,

Comment: The above code filters with p_id and updates all records, regardless of checking whether all other columns are same or not

Comment: Delete all record first, then try

Comment: okay, let me check it. one mn.

Comment: are p_id and unit_id make uniques?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94199/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-sohel-rana).